# Убрать лишние знаки экранирования

Tags: python, json

Моя программа занимается парсингом сайта, в коде html находится json словарь, у которого кавычки (") экранированы, я не могу их удалить через replace, если взять этот json, вставить в python:

```
> string='{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"Организация \\\"ООО Спорт Плюс\\\".\"}'
```

то python автоматически их уберет и ничего делать не надо

```
> {"Id":1,"Name":"Организация \"ООО Спорт Плюс\"."}
```

, но если эта строка парсится, то python автоматически экранирует еще раз уже сами слэш слэш, .replace('','') и подобные не удаляет их, а в итоге мне надо из строки получить json,а именно json.loads(string). Вот исходная строка:

```
{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"Организация \\\"ООО Спорт Плюс\\\".\"}
```

Comment: Не понял, почему `replace()` не подходит. https://repl.it/repls/QuestionableSupportiveDevelopments

Comment: Вообще, нужно смотреть как этот json парсится, возможно при этом парсинге обрезаются кавычки.

Answer (score 1):

[`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```py
import ast  # Модуль для парсинга литералов в python объекты
import json


json_string = ast.literal_eval(  # Спарсить строку как литерал
        f"'{string}'"  # Внутренние кавычки, чтобы литерал воспринялся как строка
)

target_json = json.loads(json_string)  # Восстанавливаем json-объект из строки
```